# How Google places API works internally for android/ios?

Tags: android, ios, google-places-api

Creating lots of uneven api hits while finding places, Eg:- finding **Manchester** using API typing **'M'** and **'A'** counts to 2 hits, click on 'Manchester' counts to 3 hits, the api count increases after many requests made. Is there any google places api hits made at   `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`